# Need to detect mousemove event in iframe without setting css pointer-events to none

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, addeventlistener

I have an **YouTube iframe** in React application. On **mousemove event**, I want to make a component appear and make it disappear when there is no mouse movement. I have figured it out for the document but when the mouse enters the YouTube iframe specifically, it doesn't work any more.

The solution of setting **"pointer-events: none"** in CSS doesn't work for me since it disables YouTube features which basically works on the pointer-events. I have also tried setting event listeners on the iframe itself using "iframe.contentWindow.document", which also didn't work.

Comment: You cannot access a foreign website in an iframe

Comment: @mplungjan This is a very important feature for the project. So there is literally no way for me to do it then?